# (discord.js) How can i make a category then add a new channel too that category

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What im trying to do is have discord.js make a category then after that make a channel then move that channel into the category if there is any possible way.

My Code Now:

```js
    if(command === 'spamcategory'){
      let amount = args.slice(0).join(" ")
      let name = args.splice(1,Infinity).join(" ")
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

      message.guild.channels.create(name, { type: "GUILD_CATEGORY" });
      
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
message.guild.channels.create(name, { type: "GUILD_CATEGORY" })
    .then(async (category) => {
        await category.createChannel('channelName');
    });
```